# Jmeter : While Controller : Loop not getting executed for second itreration

Tags: loops, jmeter

I am working on simple JMeter script and using WHILE controller.
When i run the test for one user and one iteration the while controller executes well.

when i run the test for one user and two (more than 1) iteration, the control does not go inside while controller

for eg 1 user and 3 iteration

Iteration 1 : while controller will be executed : Iteration will Pass
Iteration 2 : while controller will be executed : Iteration will Fail
Iteration 3 : while controller will be executed : Iteration will Fail

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the condition that you specified in `While Controller`? Please add screenshot.

Comment: @Naveen   Adding condition for reference , 

${__javaScript("${file_status}"!="UNPUBLISHED")}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My expectation is that you need to **reset** your `${file_status}` variable value at the beginning of the 2nd iteration, not knowing the details of your Test Plan I can suggest only doing it via [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), the code will be as simple as:

```
vars.put("file_status", "something not equal to UNPUBLISHED")
```

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in scope, the above code will set `${file_status}` variable value to something different from `UNPUBLISHED` so on 2nd and further iterations your While Controller will be executed as well.

See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: I see two JSR223 under Pre and Post processer which is more preferable

Comment: If you place PreProcessor as a child of the request it will execute before the request, PostProcessor will be executed after it. I'm not telepathic enough to suggest which one to use, JSR223 Sampler placed before the While Controller will definitely work

Comment: It worked well this time... simply implemented what you suggested , added JSR223 Sampler before WHILE and reset them to some other value :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Dmitri T